# Inverse trigonometric differentiation

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, inverse

See f(x)=sin$^-$$^1$(2$^x$$^+$$^1$/4$^x$+1) is equal to g(x) = 2tan$^-$$^1$(2$^x$) for all less than zero so the derivative of f(x) will be equal derivative of g(x)  for all x ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for all $x < 0$. If two graphs are the same over a range of $x$ values, their slopes are the same as well within that range of $x$ values. You can see a comparison here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wayajegres